# Workflow settings : Require manage Lists permissions to start the workflow In SharePoint 2013 Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

[image]What this setting means? Because when I start the workflow, it is showing error message.

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

That option means that in order for a user to manually start the workflow, he needs to have a permission level that allows him to modify the permissions of the list. One of the permission levels that allows a user to do this is the "**Full Control**" permission level.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have Contribute level permission , When i start workflow  it show  alert like ""Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" is it for this option or something else?

Comment: The "Contribute" permission level is definitely not enough for you to run the workflow if the option is enabled. Try getting "Full Control" permissions and start the workflow afterwards and it should work fine. Or disable the option and it should also work fine with just "Contribute" permissions.

Comment: So how can i remove this permission so i can run workflow? B'ce when i uncheck and click on next button it show alert "please select workflow Template".

Comment: Since you say that you have "Contribute" permissions you should not be able to view the workflow settings page. Do you use two different accounts?  Also, selecting a workflow template should be an option on the same page where the "Require Manage Lists Permissions to start the workflow" option is.

Comment: No i am able to view the workflow settings please see the attachment.

Comment: Well, you just need to select the workflow template at the top of the page where is says "Select a workflow template". This is strange because I thought you already have created the workflow and you're just trying to modify it. Is this not the case?

Comment: Already have created the workflow i am just modify the workflow but when i start the workflow it show alert  "Something went wrong. To try again, reload the page and then start the workflow" this is my main problem. this happen only for my old one but when  i create new workflow it work.